# pid=container:X in docker-compose does not respect depends_on, any workaround?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose including:

```yaml
services:
  my_container:
    image: my_image
    container_name:my_container

  my_second_container:
    image: my_image
    container_name: my_second_container
    pid: "container:my_container"
    depends_on:
      - my_container
```

I would like to access the processes of the second container from the first one. This works fine with docker run and starting them one by one, but when executing in a compose, I get:

ERROR: Service 'my_second_container' uses the PID namespace of container 'my_container' which does not exist.

Is there a solution to that, or something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does work if you use `service:my_container` instead. How ever the `depends_on` option is ignored when you restart your project.

```yaml
services:
  my_container:
    image: my_image
    container_name:my_container

  my_second_container:
    image: my_image
    container_name: my_second_container
    pid: "service:my_container"
    depends_on:
      - my_container
```